# "while True" intermediate solutions

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm working with big multidimensional arrays. I want to know after x loops the values S,S2,E,E2
I want to find all the solutions of a loop.
I have a code that iterates with a greedy. My output is a list of numers. I want to save the arrays that generate those numbers. My code:

```
while True:
       if f2<f:
           f,S,S2=f2,E,E2 # f is a value and S and E are arrays
           ......
            print f2-f
        else: 
           break
```

If i run this code I have a list of f2-f but I need also to save the f,S,S2,f2,E,E2 created in each passage of the while.. Thank you

Comment: First, the code in your post is improperly formatted - please fix this. Second, what do you mean "save the [...] created in each passage"? Would simply printing them out suffice?

Comment: It is still incorrectly formatted.

Comment: print and pipe to a file?

Comment: Ty @inspectorG4dget. No I want to put them in intermadiate arrays or I want to know after n loops them values

Comment: This is probably rewritten as a generator that does `while f2 < f: ... yield f2-f` but your code is improperly formatted and there is no example input/output.  So who knows.

Comment: You could save each iteration result in a list. You would need to copy those variables if they are modified. I could be something like: `results.append((f, S[:], S2[:], f2, E[:], E2[:]))`

Comment: @roippi: I think he'd want to yield `f, S, S2, f2, E, E2` or something (since he wants to save all of the matching values whenever there's a match). But otherwise, yeah, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: I think that @bvidal solution could work. I'm trying

Comment: But where I have to add this code @bvidal? Into the loop or out?

Comment: I know that all the values are different but I'm working with big arrays..

Comment: You would need to create the `results` list before the `while` loop and "save" the variables where the `print` statement is in the code you posted. But if you're working with big arrays that's maybe not a good idea to copy everything every time. Also take a look into [generators](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) as proposed by @roippi

Comment: Another option for working with big arrays is to use something like `array` to eliminate all the overhead of "boxing" all those numbers up (which can turn every 8-byte integer into a 72-byte `int` object). Or, even better, use NumPy, which gives you `ndarray` objects that store like an `array`, but also let you replace those explicit loops with array-wide operations (which are not just a lot simpler to read, but also an order of magnitude or so faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
results = []
while True:
       if f2<f:
           f,S,S2=f2,E,E2 # f is a value and S and E are arrays
           ......
           results.append((f,S,S2,E,E2))
           print f2-f
           print "intermediate result:", results[-1]
        else: 
           break
```